# jQuery/PHP Validation From Common Source

Tags: php, jquery, xml, json

I have a Model class for a Generic Object that contains an array of validations to perform for input. Similar to:

```
class Dog extends GenericObject
{
    $this->validations = array ( "breed" => array ("max_length" => 15) );
}
```

This is all fine and dandy but I'm trying to work out a way to assess the validity of a certain field via javascript. So far I've been using an AJAX call that fires off to Controller to check the Model. Great. However, for certain validations such as length, matches regular expression, it seems ridiculously system intensive to be calling PHP.

I know I could obviously just repeat the validations in Javascript but I know there has to be a way to do it without repeating my validations. I thought of a common JSON or XML file but these would be editable and could therefore be vulnerable.

Do you have any suggestions as to how best achieve this goal?

**Edit: I also considered having PHP generate the relevant jQuery validations but didn't think this would be considered terribly good form?**

Comment: What do you mean by *"I thought of a common JSON or XML file but these would be editable and could therefore be vulnerable"*? If files on your server are editable, you probably have a serius security breach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we do is define all our validation rules in our (PHP) Models and then generate the relevant jQuery validation rules from those base rules. This works fine, but the only drawback is that when you use non-trivial validation methods you end up defining your custom method in the Javascript as well. For us this is just a minor drawback as we don't have many of those rules, so I guess it depends on your situation if it's a good method for you.

I would love to hear of some other (better) methods however.